# Any alternative of GetIpAddrTable?

Tags: .net, c++, network-programming, firmware

I am looking the alternative of “GetIpAddrTable” method because I am having some problems due to this function.

As mentions in remarks:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365949(v=vs.85).aspx
[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365949%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> Manually resetting a network interface card (NIC) and certain PnP events may result in an IP address being removed or changed.

While acquiring IP address, when I sent reset AT Command “at*e2reset” by TeraTerm in order to stop firmware working, then I am totally unable to get IP.
Is there any way to handle this problem? May be it’s possible by changing some logic in code, but I don’t know.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you use WMI instead. It fetches information directly from the TCP/IP stack implementation, as well as any state reported to WMI directly by your network driver. As such, it's much more reliable as a source for this kind of information.

Take a look at the [Win32_NetworkAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394216.aspx) WMI class and this article on [using WMI in C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa389762.aspx), or the [System.Management.Instrumentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.instrumentation.aspx) namespace for .NET.

Comment: what is the linux equivalent ?